# What would the diagram look like for this problem?

Tags: trigonometry

**Question:**

Kevin is standing at the top of a ladder.  The ladder is $7$m long.  It is propped against a tree, and makes an angle of $70^\circ$ with the ground.  To check his aim, Kevin is tossing balls into a basket located $5.4$m from the base of the ladder, on the opposite side of the tree.

a) 
 Determine the distance of the base of the ladder from the tree, in meters.

b) If Kevins eyes are even with the top of the ladder and he looks down on the basket, what is the angle of depression? Answer in nearest degree.

What would the diagram for this problem look like?

Answer (score 0):

Here $x$ is the distance between the base of the ladder and the tree and $\theta$ is the angle of depression.
[image]